# how to operate two adjacent objects in java8 function style,change below codes

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

the latter StaffOperInfo object need to compare with the former one,how to change below code to java8 style?My English is poor,I hope you would not mind, Thanks!

```
        StaffOperInfo before = null;
        for (StaffOperInfo so : staffMap.get(staffId)) {
            if (before == null) {
                before = so;
            } else {
                if (so.getTermIp()!=null&&!so.getTermIp().equals(before.getTermIp()) 
                        && so.getAcceptDate().getTime()-
                        before.getAcceptDate().getTime()<step*1000) {
                    if (filterMap.containsKey(staffId)) {
                        filterMap.get(staffId).add(before);
                        filterMap.get(staffId).add(so);
                    } else {
                        List<StaffOperInfo> ll = new ArrayList<>();
                        ll.add(before);
                        ll.add(so);
                        filterMap.put(staffId, ll);
                    }
                }
                before = so;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams won't make your code necessarily better. That said below is one of the way of doing it if your collection is a List or an Array(if not, this wont work):

```
List<StaffOperInfo> list = staffMap.get(staffId);
IntStream.range(1, list.size() - 1) // Stream on Indices of the List
        .mapToObj(i -> new StaffOperInfo[]{list.get(i - 1), list.get(i)})  //  Get pair of StaffOperInfo
        .filter(arr -> !Objects.equals(arr[0].getTermIp(), arr[1].getTermIp()) // Filter pairs based on your if condition
                && (arr[1].getAcceptDate().getTime() - arr[0].getAcceptDate().getTime() < step * 1000))
        .forEach(arr -> {
            if (filterMap.containsKey(staffId))
                filterMap.get(staffId).addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
            else
                filterMap.put(staffId, Arrays.asList(arr));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Dark posted, It's not easy/simple to do it by the native Stream API. but you can try [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
StreamEx.of(staffMap.get(staffId)).forPairs((before, so) -> {
    if (so.getTermIp()!=null&&!so.getTermIp().equals(before.getTermIp()) 
            && so.getAcceptDate().getTime()-
            before.getAcceptDate().getTime()<step*1000) {
        List<StaffOperInfo> ll = filterMap.computeIfAbsent(staffId, k -> new ArrayList<>());
        ll.add(before);
        ll.add(so);
    }
});
```